# Spark Enhance Join between Terabytes of Datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have five `Hive` tables assume the names is A, B, C, D, and E. For each table there is a customer_id as the key for join between them. Also, Each table contains at least 100:600 columns all of them is `Parquet` format.

Example of one table below:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a 
(
customer_id Long, 
col_1 STRING,
col_2 STRING,
col_3 STRING,
.
.
col_600 STRING
)
STORED AS PARQUET;
```

I need to achieve two points,

- Join all of them together with the most optimum way using Spark Scala. I tried to `sortByKey` before join but still there is a performance bottleneck. I tried to `reparation` by key before join but the performance is still not good. I tried to increase the parallelism for Spark to make it 6000 with many executors but not able to achieve a good results.
- After join I need to apply a separate function for some of these columns.

Sample of the join I tried below,

```
val dsA =  spark.table(table_a)
val dsB =  spark.table(table_b) 
val dsC =  spark.table(table_c) 
val dsD =  spark.table(table_d) 
val dsE =  spark.table(table_e) 
val dsAJoineddsB = dsA.join(dsB,Seq(customer_id),"inner")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case the direct join is not the optimal case. You can acheive this task using the below simple way.

- First, create case class for example `FeatureData` with two fields `case class FeatureData(customer_id:Long, featureValue:Map[String,String])`
- Second, You will map each table to FeatureData case class key, [feature_name,feature_value]
- Third, You will `groupByKey` and `union` all the dataset with the same key.

I the above way it will be faster to union than join. But it need more work.

After that, you will have a dataset with key,map. You will apply the transformation for `key, Map(feature_name)`.

Simple example of the implementation as following:
You will map first the `dataset` to the `case class` then you can union all of them. After that you will `groupByKey` then map it and reduce it.

```
case class FeatureMappedData(customer_id:Long, feature: Map[String, String])
val dsAMapped = dsA.map(row ⇒
        FeatureMappedData(row.customer_id,
          Map("featureA" -> row.featureA,
            "featureB" -> row.featureB)))
val unionDataSet = dsAMapped  union dsBMapped 
unionDataSet.groupByKey(_.customer_id)
      .mapGroups({
        case (eid, featureIter) ⇒ {
      val featuresMapped: Map[String, String] = featureIter.map(_.feature).reduce(_ ++ _).withDefaultValue("0") 
      FeatureMappedData(customer_id, featuresMapped)
    }
  })
```

Comment: You idea seems nice but could you please give me some snippet code explain how to apply it. I am still new in Spark and Scala and can't get the idea to be implemented.

Comment: Please have a look again

Comment: Thanks, It works too much better. Do you have any other idea to enhance the performance more?